# Penetration test on a infotainment system platform

Tags: android, nmap, metasploit, vehicle

I am pentesting an infotainment platform that is still under development. I did a nmap scan (for all ports with option `-p-`) of the platform and found a few open ports.

```
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
3490/tcp  open  colubris
5355/tcp  open  llmnr
8888/tcp  open  sun-answerbook
9999/tcp  open  abyss
16509/tcp open  unknown
51331/tcp open  unknown
58485/tcp open  unknown
```

Doing a `netcat` on the ports did not yield any information except for port `3490`. On port `3490`, I could read some logs that are being used by the IVI-Graphics, some IP logs (with service IDs), etc. I have also obtained some process and thread IDs of applications that are running on the system. I have also tried `telnet` on all open ports and it did not yield me any more information. I have done `service version` scans on all ports as well, it did not yield any significant information. I have searched for metasploit modules, but for the services mentioned above, there are not any existing ones.

However, now I am stuck and unable to proceed any further. Does anyone have any other suggestions on going further?

Secondly, I know that the IVI system runs Linux and Android. Right now, I am in the subnet of Linux. Linux and Android have a private virtual network between them. Is there any way, I can reach the virtual network and perform further pentest of android?

---

I did a bit of digging with `rpcbind` and found out the below information.

```
Kali Machine : 192.168.1.20
Infotainment system : 192.168.1.11

$ rpcinfo  192.168.1.11
program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp6      ::.0.111               portmapper superuser
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /run/rpcbind.sock      portmapper superuser
```

I wanted to investigate which applications are using the current open ports mentioned in the `nmap` scan. Hence I used `netstat` on the infotainment system. The system does not support `lsof` or `ss`. The netstat also lacks the `-p` option that provides program information. `netstat` supports the following options `[-ral] [-tuwx] [en]`.
Here is the output of `netstat`

```
root@infotainment-system:~# netstat -lutxn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48717           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9999            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16509           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50753           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::16509                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::3490                 :::*                    LISTEN
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30490           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.23.0.2:30490         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 10.23.0.2:30499         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55897           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60805           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 :::5353                 :::*
udp        0      0 :::5355                 :::*
udp        0      0 :::57031                :::*
udp        0      0 ::1:53                  :::*
udp        0      0 :::111                  :::*
```

With this information, it is unable to find out which programs are actually using the ports that are open.

---

I found out that the `portmapper` is vulnerable to port amplification attacks. So I used the following metasploit module to further initiate an attack:

```
msf5 > use auxiliary/scanner/portmap/portmap_amp 

msf5 auxiliary(scanner/portmap/portmap_amp) > set RHOSTS => 192.168.1.11
msf5 auxiliary(scanner/portmap/portmap_amp) > run

[*] Sending Portmap RPC probes to 192.168.1.11->192.168.1.11 (1 hosts)
[+] 192.168.1.11:111 - Vulnerable to Portmap RPC DUMP (Program version: 3) amplification: No packet amplification and a 17x, 644-byte bandwidth amplification
[+] 192.168.1.11:111 - Vulnerable to Portmap RPC GETSTAT amplification: No packet amplification and a 7x, 244-byte bandwidth amplification
[*] Scanned 1 of 1 hosts (100% complete)
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed
```

Executing the metasploit attack, the output states that the target is vulnerable to `rpc-dump` and `rpc getstat`. I am new to metasploit, so I am not aware of how metasploit interprets the attack and spits the output. I have read about [port amplification attack](https://kb.iweb.com/hc/en-us/articles/230267968-Guide-to-Portmapper-Amplification-Issues) and can understand what's happening. However, I do not understand the output of metasploit.

Does it mean that my target is vulnerable to these attacks? If so, what is the simplest way in which I can create a small concept for the attack?

Comment: Are you able to gain a copy of the firmware, or a shell on the device? Those would be my next steps.

Comment: Since the system is under development, I am able to get a SSH on the device. Port 22 is also open, but I did not mention it above in the question. The reason being that with the final system, the SSH access will be blocked. I am unable to get a shell via any of the other ports mentioned above. Also coming to a copy of firmware, this is available however, from the internal repository that we have. Is there a way to extract the firmware from the system itself?

Comment: yes, it may be possible if any shell access is gained, or with physical access to the device. I get that things will be locked down for the final deployment, but it can speed up the vulnerability discovery process if you are able to introspect things.

Comment: Port 111 being open implies it might have NFS services exposed.

Comment: I've tested infotainment systems before. The best option is generally to look for hardware pins on the board that expose UART, so that you can get a serial terminal on the device and run commands, assuming the interface isn't locked down. You can ask the client/vendor to give you information on that, since you're likely more time constrained than an attacker would be. It'll probably be running VxWorks or a similar Unix-like RTOS, so it should have a shell environment. Once you've got a shell on the device you can start dumping off binaries and reversing them.

Comment: @multithr3at3d Could you give me some hints on how to proceed with extracting the firmware? I do have a root access via SSH, but as I said, this will be disabled in the future for final deployment.

Comment: @Polynomial Sure thing.  I do have a UART access to the board for development purposes. I can also login as root for the linux system. There's no RTOS running for now, but VXWorks will be added in the coming stages of development. Currently its running Linux and Android with a hypervisor setup for infotainment(Android) and Cluster(Linux) displays.

Comment: @Polynomial, If the NFS services are running, it should have come up in the port scan, right? they dont show up in the nmap scans for now

Comment: "port amplification" just means a small UDP packet can get a big UDP packet (or many packets) in response, which can be used as an amplifier in a DDoS attack on some other target. It's not a vulnerability, it's a threat.

Comment: @bonsaiviking : so it means my infotainment system can be used to attack another target?

Comment: @gst Yes it does

Comment: Please don't edit in new questions that are tangents to the original question. Your post is growing arms and legs.

Comment: Have you looked at the `netstat` documentation to see the switch that will tell you the program that is using the ports?

Comment: @schroeder : yes, i have checked all the netstat options. Unfortunately the netstat that is available in infotainment system supports only the following options `[-ral] [-tuwx] [en]`. Unfortunately the `-p` option is not supported which provides the program name. That is why I was looking out for different options.

Comment: Then the lack of `-p` might be a useful fact to add... else we'll just point you to that option ...

Comment: Also, I've made several edits and you rolled back all of them. Please don't do that. You have an irrelevant tag, spelling errors, spacing errors, and there is no need to include the "Edits" since edit history is available. I also removed your *tangential* question, which I explained.

Comment: Actually, I'm just going to close this question. You have a target and you don't know what to do with it. We could come up with a hundred different approaches. And you are also asking for help with lots of little tangential aspects and problems you've run into. If you can refine and focus the question into something specific instead of asking for a plan on how to test a black box, we can take a look at it,

Comment: The reason for rollback, was that the sequence of the question and its edits were mismatched as compared to the original question. The whole idea of asking the question was getting to a broader approach towards testing and ideas for penetration testing. This was quite evident in the question itself. It would have been useful for someone who wants to do this in future, considering the lack of information available on the internet for infotainment pentest.

Comment: The problem is that with the details you have, it doesn't matter that it's an "infotainment system" or any other system. Your question boils down to "I have a black box system; how do I test it?" and that's not answerable in a Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, not knowing for sure the protocols you are facing I might be tempted to look more closely at the packets, so one thing you could do is use a tool like [Scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for probing ports and perhaps capture the exchange with Wireshark too.

Nmap is a wonderful tool, but it also makes educated guesses and interprets results for you, which is not always sufficient.

But let's assume you are on the same local network and that a LLMNR service is indeed running on that machine. You could perhaps send queries to it in an effort to try to gain more insight into the network (this is after all a resolver). Nmap even has a script for this: [llmnr-resolve](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/llmnr-resolve.html)

An even better scenario (but which is far from certain) is that other machines are sending broadcast requests to that service, then you could possibly intercept those queries and send poisoned responses with a tool like [Responder](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/Responder), to trick those machines into talking to a malicious host controlled by you. See below for an article which explains the attack in details.

Last but not least, by default nmap only scans the 1000 most common ports on TCP, which means that if run with default options, you could miss interesting ports. I am mentioning this since you did not provide the nmap command line that was used to gather the results.

### References

[NetBIOS and LLMNR: The Gifts That Keep on Giving (Away Credentials)](https://www.crowe.com/cybersecurity-watch/netbios-llmnr-giving-away-credentials)

Comment: I have used `nmap` with the `-p-` option. (updated in the question). I did use the script `llmnr-resolve` earlier as part of exploring the options for nmap. The result is as shown: ```$ sudo nmap --script llmnr-resolve --script-args 'llmnr-resolve.hostname=`www.google.com' -p 5355 192.168.1.11 ```     
 ```NSE: [llmnr-resolve] Nsock connect failed immediately
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.11
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5355/tcp open  llmnr
MAC Address: 00:12:34:56:78:90 (Camille Bauer)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.30 seconds
```

Comment: As with the second case you mentioned about 'other machines sending broadcast requests'. This is not currently the case. Currently, the system is an ARM A.76 processor, that runs Linux and Android. I am on local network with Linux. Linux and Android share a virtual network between them to interact.  There are no external devices connected for now.